# Count non blank lines

Tags: shell, count, wc

I am using `wc -l` to count the number of lines I get as output from `docker ps` command. Sometimes there are no containers in the list and it just gives empty line but `wc -l` counts that as well and says the answer as 1. How can I avoid this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the count option of `grep` and `dot` means any character which is not blank.

```
docker ps|grep -c .
```

Answer (score 0):

Use instead a better-for-programs docker ps output `-q`. It only displays containers ids

```
docker ps -q | wc -l
```